# onclick or onClick?

Tags: javascript, onclick

I thought that binding the click event in javascript is done by using `node.onclick`, and Chrome/Firefox seem to agree with me, but I saw it written `.onClick` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380415/how-can-i-give-a-limit-to-an-append-function-with-javascript/4380487#4380487) 4 times by 3 people, so it can't be a typo and I doubt that it's a coincidence.

So, why are people writing `onClick` when it does not work?

<s>**UPDATE**: There are two good explanations; I don't know which one of them is the most plausible, so I will accept the answer based on popular vote, tomorrow.</s>

Comment: One more thing to add: if the old XHTML DOCTYPE is used, all attributes must be in lower case.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Because some browsers (depending on the DOCTYPE) are tolerant of the inline `onClick="something();"` attribute...it seems to have spread a bit, even into JavaScript questions where it doesn't work, since case matters.

Also, specifically to stackoverflow...people using it in questions...well, most of the time they wouldn't be asking a question if their code worked :)

Comment: well I thought about that, but ... did it spread _that_ much?

Comment: @Gabi - yup, that's the best I can figure, based on all the questions I've seen it popup in, and the inline attributes used by the same users.

Comment: There's also the equivalent method in ActionScript which people often have as `onClick` that causes further mutation.

Answer (score 15):

@Nick Craver pretty much has it nailed down and has my vote; I just wanted to add my thought.

I think it's `onClick` is often used in conversation because it's a bit more readable, and as an old habit from those of us who predate all lowercase HTML.  However, in code - both JavaScript and HTML, `onclick` is correct and the only way it should appear.  Even if you're using an older HTML doctype, stick to lowercase.  If you ever update to a more strict doctype, you'll be glad your code doesn't need to be checked for case.

Answer (score 12):

It's just that for most browsers HTML attributes are case insensitive, but JS is case-sensitive. onClick will work in html, but if you're defining the handler in JS, you need to use the lowercased onclick.

Comment: in XHTML, HTML attributes are case sensitive.  Most browsers will understand and render it fine, but your code will fail validation.

Comment: hmm. Lax browser handling must have been what I was reading. I just read something about this the other week.

Answer (score 1):

In that specific question, I used "onClick" as the original question had it in that vein and I try to change as little of the OPs code as possible to make a solution, so that they can see their mistake easily.

The camel case is invalid technically, though I like camel case in general.  Frankly, it always annoys me when I see that method, as I think "Where's jQuery!".

It is heavily prevalent in the world, I see it all the time in source.

I edited my answer on the referenced question to fit, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Anyone like to explain the -1?