# Custom jQuery function not working?

Tags: jquery, function

I've been designing a site for awhile now, and I've run into a stand-still.

Not sure why, but the function I made `$.show_message` works just fine if I call it right after it's initialized in the JavaScript file. But when I try to call it in an `onclick` event, or anywhere else, I get the following error:

Error: attempt to run compile-and-go script on a cleared scope

The source code is at: http://71.238.252.43/java/message.js

I can't call messages in any other fashion than by using the function at the end of the JavaScript file, and I'm getting frustrated.

I've tried turning the `$.` functions into normal functions, removing the `(function($){` at the top, along with the ending part at the bottom `})(jQuery);`, and nothing seems to fix it. I'm using the latest version of FireFox and Windows 7 64 bit.

Any help on this matter would be much appreciated, as I've pretty much run out of ideas.

Comment: Post your code here. Post example usage (what works, what does not) also.

Comment: @Jasper: `onclick` event is not the same as `onClick` event ([see here for more information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380719/onclick-or-onclick)).

Comment: Well, for example, if I add this at the end of the message.js file:

$.show_message("Hello!", { title:"Caption" });

It will show the message, with the caption "Caption" just fine.

But trying to call it anywhere else on my site seems to throw back that scope error.

What I want to happen, is when a DIV is clicked, it will show a message.

I've tried using onclick and onClick inside of the div, and the error persists.

I've also tried this:

$("#announcements_button").click(function() { $.show_message("Hi!"); });

Still gives the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `document.write()` once the page has loaded.  Instead, append an element to the DOM and write it's innerHTML:

```
$("<div>").appendTo("body").html("Your HTML Here");
```

`document.write()` is being called in `$.check_first()` which is called by `$.show_message()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring your functions inside of of the `document.ready` event handler, if you want the functions to be available globally (which is needed since you are declaring `onclick` events inline) then try attaching your function to the `$.fn` object: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

You can also bind your events inside the `document.ready` event handler rather than inline.