# Javascript OnClick event

Tags: javascript, public-html

Here's a bit of code from a simple currency converter I'm building. The `calculate()` script runs fine, but the `clear()` code refuses to work and it appears the same??

```
<a href="#" OnCLick="calculate();">US - CDN</a>
<a href="#" OnCLick="clear();">Clear</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function clear() {
            document.getElementById('us-cdn1').innerHTML = '';
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function calculate() {
        var amount = parseFloat(document.getElementById("amount").value);
        var result = document.getElementById("amount");
            result.value = (amount).toFixed(2);
        var result = document.getElementById("amount1");
            result.value = (amount * .9861932938856016).toFixed(2); 
            document.getElementById('us-cdn').innerHTML = 'US';
            document.getElementById('us-cdn1').innerHTML = 'CDN';
    }

</script>
```

Comment: sorry, bad post... the tag was closed... The calculate script works fine... just the clear is failing

Comment: Never mind, I see your comment

Comment: btw... appreciate your quick answer... anything else look wrong there... I'm really scratching my head!

Comment: also btw... if I execute from withing the ref it works fine there... I just want the script outside so I can call it from if statements I'll be building in later... but if this simple thing fails... I don't like my odds of adding that code!
:)

Comment: I recommend you use jQuery and add your listeners afterwards. Have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9bew2/)

Comment: Why are there two script tags? What happens if you include the clear() function in the second script tag?

Comment: just make the C capital of clear function

Comment: @Arpit that's defying the holy javascript naming convention rules

Comment: Here is a good explanation about clear() 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165570/is-clear-a-reserved-word-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks everyone
iPhoneing this in remotely but
The public function is it
clearField()
Works a charm
I'll look further at the more elegant suggestions but I really appreciate the responses everyone!!

Answer (score 1):

`clear()` is a public function. Change it into:

```
<a href="#" onclick="clearField();">Clear</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function clearField() {
        document.getElementById('us-cdn1').innerHTML = '';
}
</script>
```

Comment: +1 - Only as a note to be 100% accurate it's actually `onclick`, you can read about it here: [onclick or onClick?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4380719/1456376)