# Calling Javascript - Window.open in PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I'm trying to call a window.open() javascript code inside a php file, but unfortunately it is not responding.

Here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<?php .....

$printHeader .= " <div id ='subHeader'><p class = 'alignleft'><font style='color:blue'>User: " . $username . " | Access: " . $level ." | <a href=logout.php>Logout</a></font></p>";  
$printHeader .= " <p class='alignright'><a href='refresh.php' onClick='window.open(this.href,'mywin','width=400,height=200')'>Refresh List</a></p></div>"; 
$printHeader .= "<div style='clear: both;'></div>";

.... ?>

</body> </html>
```

Unfortunately, when I run it, it doesn't work at all. Can we not call javascript in php? Please advise!

Thanks!

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: What does the javascript console say? Does it show any errors?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Does your PHP contain `echo $printHeader` anywhere?

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is related to the quotes, Your inner single quotes are ending the onClick string, so replacing the outter single quotes to double quotes(will keeping the inner quotes single) will solve your issue. try changing this:

```
onClick='window.open(this.href,'mywin','width=400,height=200)'
```

To this:

```
onClick=\"window.open(this.href,'mywin','width=400,height=200)\"
```

Here's an example:

[On JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H3zKT/)

Another solution is to simply escape your inner quotes by prefixing them with a backslash (`\`).

Comment: `onClick` != `onclick` in all browsers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380719/onclick-or-onclick

Comment: Make sure to escape the onClick double quotes from within the PHP double quotes `onClick=\"window.open(...)\"`

Comment: @SetSailMedia I was speaking from Javascript perspective. Anyway, I edit it.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that catches my eye right away is that you did not escape your single quotes withing the `onclick` event. Modify it like so:

```
onclick=\"window.open(this.href, 'mywin', width=400, height=200);\"
```

See if this helps you out.