# How to get attribute of div without ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

My website contain lot of images and thats why i cannot give ID for each image it will be tedious task. I need to get the source attribute of image tag but i am not able to do it without ID.
I did try for attr() and getAttribute() but it doesn`t seems to work for me.

**My Code**

```
<img src="./images/image1.jpg" width='100' height='100' alt='Sample image' onClick='imageInfo(this);'>

<script>
function imageInfo()
{
    alert(this.src);
}
</script>
```

i am trying to get the source of image tag but it is not coming 
i have also tried in jsfiddle but it is not working .

[JS FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/LgLzh/14/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yL5cf/1/

Comment: You needed to change your options in your fiddle, @hitesh.  you had the javascript set to run on onload, when it should have been in the body.  http://jsfiddle.net/LgLzh/24/

Comment: what's with all the downvotes?  is this you?  we are answering your question; if not, you need to clarify what you are asking for by making comments or changing your initial post.

Comment: your code is perfect but placed in wrong place just check it out http://jsfiddle.net/LgLzh/32/

Comment: Using `onclick function` in all the img tags is not a good method as you would have nightmare if you were to make a small change. Add a class and then using jquery you can get this to work.

Comment: @RoyMJ : thanks that is some valuable comment :)

Comment: @rajeshkakawat: Thanks ur code works just one question why is it not working wen i put it in java script panel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try something like this. Because you have passed the object of image but not used in function

```
<script>
    function imageInfo(obj)
    {
        alert(obj.src);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi it is right answer !!! i like it because of ur jsfiddle example thanks for sharing answer ... http://jsfiddle.net/LgLzh/32/

Comment: You can also leave your function as it is and call it using `onclick='imageInfo.call(this)'`.

Answer (score 5):

From your fiddle,

```
function imageInfo(this)
{
    alert('image');
    alert(this.src);
}
```

This happened because of `this` is a **reserved keyword**.

```
 function imageInfo (e)
{
    alert('image');
    alert(e.src);
}
```

Also **`onclick`** not `onClick`, to know the reason check this [**SO answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4380741/1671639)

check this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LgLzh/28/)

Answer (score 3):

You can always do this:

**HTML**

```
<img src="https://www.google.ca/images/srpr/logo4w.png" width='100' height='100' alt="Sample image">
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('img').click(function() {
    window.alert($(this).attr('src'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QB6Da/

Comment: so instead of using onclick i can directly go for jquery click event ...hmmm good idea !!! ...

Answer (score 2):

To just fix your code, you need to pass the control to the javascript function:

```
<img src="./images/image1.jpg" width='100' height='100' alt='Sample image' onClick='imageInfo(this);'>

<script>
function imageInfo(control)
{
    alert(control.src);
}
</script>
```

Comment: whoever is downvoting this needs to provide a comment.  this fixes his issue as he requested, and I even provided a jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/LgLzh/24/  You guys suck.

Comment: what do you mean by passing `control`?  Is that a keyword?

Comment: no, that's the name of your parameter.  onclick passes the control (this) as a parameter to the imageInfo function.  Inside imageInfo, your control will now be accessed by the variable name control.  You can set that to whatever you want; I use variable and parameter names that make sense.  'imgControl' could also work.  Whatever is relevant to you and your app.

Comment: This answer is correct. "control" is just a parameter, you can't use "this" as a function parameter, that's why it wasn't working. Also, make sure that you use some kind of htaccess to disallow crawling of images as search engines will not index you if they have  to consume resources when they crawl each img...

Comment: I know it is a parameter, but you're missing to explain that in your answer.  That's why I pointed in comments.  Hope you understand :)

Comment: If I had to explain everything about everything in my comments, I'd be here all day.

Answer (score 2):

In your example you have to put the clicked Object as a parameter for the function:

```
function imageInfo(img)
{
    alert(img.src);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged this as jQuery, this should work :

http://jsfiddle.net/LgLzh/20/

```
$(function() {
    $('img').each(function() {
        console.log($(this).attr('src')); 
    });
});
```

Or this if you wanna react when it gets clicked : http://jsfiddle.net/LgLzh/26/

```
$(function() {
    $('img').on('click', function() {
        console.log($(this).attr('src')); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. This will be help for you

```
  $('img').click(function() {
        alert(this.src); 
});
```

Demo [`Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/subhash9/LgLzh/39/)

Comment: Fiddle isn't enough.  When attaching a fiddle it would have shown a message **"please add your code here"**. This is not nice, a good reason will be a better one.

Comment: @Subhash : i have to agree your code is jquery and much simpler than OneOfOne ...thanks

Comment: i cannot accept ur answer because if i have 500 images and out of 500 if i want to use only 100 than i need to add class and do this. Anyways i have given upvote for this one and i still feel that  @rajesh answer is what i need ...thanks

Answer (score 1):

This will get you the `src` of each image clicked on the page.
You do however need jQuery for this to work.

```
$('img').on('click', function (event) {
    console.log(event.target.src);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LgLzh/42/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 $('img').on('click',function(){
            alert($(this).attr('src'));
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `onclick function` in all the `img tags` is not a good method as you would have nightmare if you were to make a small change. Add a class and then using jquery you can get this to work. See the following.

Using `class` attribute :

```
<img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-uyvTMZ3dFPs/UKHsc_ZbysI/AAAAAAAACvo/QdVAlVBbUxE/s320/1hello.jpg" class="image"/><br>
<img src="http://hearstcommerce.ca/customcontent/members/premium/sample.jpg" class="image" /><br>
<img src="http://www.find-a-job-online.org/images/picture.gif" class="image"/>
```

Script :

```
$(".image").click(function(){
   var src = $(this).attr('src');
   alert("SRC = " + src);
});
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/yL5cf/6/

Comment: @hitesh :  yes it is.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-uyvTMZ3dFPs/UKHsc_ZbysI/AAAAAAAACvo/QdVAlVBbUxE/s320/1hello.jpg" width='400' height='400' alt='Sample_image' class="img">
```

other answers are short and correct, but incase you want to use jQuery...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function imageInfo(img)
        {
            var src = $(img).attr("src");
            alert(src);
        };
    $(".img").click(function(){
        imageInfo(this);
    });
});
```

and also, "this" is a reserved keyword.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/LgLzh/25/

Due to several reasons, you should define the function to the window area.

```
window.imageInfo = function (source) {
    alert('image');
    alert(source);
}
```

Comment: may i know what are those reasons

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-uyvTMZ3dFPs/UKHsc_ZbysI/AAAAAAAACvo/QdVAlVBbUxE/s320/1hello.jpg" width='400' height='400' alt='Sample_image'>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').click(function(e){        
        alert($(this).attr('src'));
    });
});
```

don't forget to include jquery to run this.
Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LgLzh/44/

Comment: Seriously we don't need jQuery everywhere, vanilla is good for simple things.

Comment: You can use your favorite one. Just that, my code works with jquery.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do...

`$('img').bind('click',function(){
            console.log($(this).attr('src'));
        });`

Comment: why do i have to bind it ??

Answer (score -1):

check the following Js fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/LgLzh/22/

```
$('img').filter(function(){
        alert($(this).attr('src'));
    });
```

Is this what you want..if not can you be more specific?

Comment: You should alert this on click event of image