# onclick button input not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Javascript code:

```
function doClick()
{
  alert("clicked");
}
```

HTML code:

```
<div >
<table border="2" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="TextFG" style="font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt;">
<tr>
<td width="100%">
  <table border="0" style="font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;Find:</td>
      <td nowrap>
        <input type="text" id="Find_Text" name="Find_Text" size="7" >&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="Find_ExactMatch" value="1" checked>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2" style="cursor:default" nowrap >Exact Match</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;In:</td>
      <td>
        <select name="Find_DataFile">
          <option value="1">Stage 1</option>
          <option value="2">Stage 2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td align="center" valign="top">
        <input type="submit" value="Go" onclick="doClick();"/>
      </td>
      <td align="center"><font class="DataFG">F2<font></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Hi all,

Simple code like the above will not fire in Chrome (latest) but will under IE8 and IE10.
Am I doing anything wrong ?.

Appreciate any help
Thanks

After stepping thru each line in the code I supplied above (which also includes a server request to populate the dropdown named "Find_DataFile" whose code I was not able to supply) I have finally found the culprit that was causing an object not defined error (because it's id was not defined and I was calling getElementById to assign it to an temp object). All working now for IE8 IE10 Chrome and Safari. Thanks guys for all the time and effort to help me find a solution. It is much appreciated. I can breathe normally now lol !

Comment: Is `doClick()` the actual function name you're using, or did you change it for the question?

Comment: It's the actual function name

Comment: Works **[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/NUNe5/)**

Comment: Need more info. Nothing is wrong with the code you posted.

Comment: For sake of simplicity there is other html code surrounding the <td></td> that I didn't include in my post. I'll try plugging it into the link provided by captain and come back if it doesnt work

Comment: Show us the complete code.

Comment: @ctaylor: Plug it into your question instead.

Comment: Open the inspector (ctr+shift+i) and check the console for any error, maybe something else if breaking your js and you think the problems is there but it's not

Comment: Amended my question to include the actual code....which works when i plug it into JSFiddle :((((

Comment: I will try what you suggest arieljuod

Comment: If I refresh the page under the Inspector will it break at the point of any errors? At the moment it is not reporting any.

Comment: What does it mean when the font color changes from black to a light brown color in the middle of javascript code ?

Comment: Have you tried onClick? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380719/onclick-or-onclick

Comment: @ctaylor When I said code, I meant the complete code. Not HTML and Javascript separately. Could you please post it as a single piece.

Comment: Upvote to Shylo for spotting the typo...would have been awesome as an answer XD

Comment: @thefourtheye It will not be possible to supply the complete code as this is company code and rather sensitive. I have made some progress tho and will report back as to my findings if anyone is interested. Thanks to all for your quick and helpful responses. Wish me luck !

Comment: onClick does not work either

Comment: @user1567453: That would have been an incorrect answer. Using `onclick` is just fine for an attribute.

Comment: After stepping thru each line in the code I supplied above (which also includes a server request to populate the dropdown named "Find_DataFile" whose code I was not able to supply) I have finally found the culprit that was causing an object not defined error (because it's id was not defined and I was calling getElementById to assign it to an temp object). All working now for IE8 IE10 Chrome and Safari. Thanks guys for all the time and effort to help me find a solution. It is much appreciated. I can breathe normally now lol !

Answer (score 1):

The submit button is a special type of button which is ONLY used inside the < form > tags. It runs whatever function you specify in the "onsubmit" attribute of the form it belongs to. Refer [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp) for an idea of how submit buttons interact with javascript and the form "onsubmit". You will be able to get the desired effect if you wire things up this way. so paying particular attention to the FORM markup the code would be...

```
<body>
    <div>
        <form name="myForm" action="http://www.google.com" onsubmit="return doClick();" method="post">
            <table border="2" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="TextFG" style="font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt;">
                <tr>
                    <td width="100%">
                      <table border="0" style="font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
                        <tr>
                          <td>&nbsp;Find:</td>
                          <td nowrap>
                            <input type="text" id="Find_Text" name="Find_Text" size="7" >&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="Find_ExactMatch" value="1" checked>
                          </td>
                          <td colspan="2" style="cursor:default" nowrap >Exact Match</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>&nbsp;In:</td>
                          <td>
                            <select name="Find_DataFile">
                              <option value="1">Stage 1</option>
                              <option value="2">Stage 2</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>
                          <td align="center" valign="top">
                            <input type="submit" value="Go" />
                          </td>
                          <td align="center"><font class="DataFG">F2<font></td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and then the javascript:

```
function doClick()
{
alert("I've been clicked");
}
```

And that works for me :)

Comment: Even though that^ is how you should handle js run on form submission I also got it working with the onClick in chrome :p

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. will try it if all else fails. Are nested <form> tags allowed ? Also onClick does not work either

Comment: There was no code posted above where you have included a <form> tag. You should NOT nest <form> tags. I would say if you have a form tag already then make sure it has the same onsubmit as the one I have above so it links to your function.

Answer (score 0):

For your sample. It should work.

There are two things you should be sure:

1. When you click the button, make sure that the Javascript code has
   been loaded.
2. Your Javascript code must not have any syntax error.
3. If the button is inside a form, after clicked, the form could be submitted.

Comment: For #1 it works under IE so I'm assuming that the JS function is loaded

Comment: Your HTML you've updated is fine. I suspect that the issue can be in your JS code.

Comment: Different browser has its own way to treat the script. For example, this object is valid in Chrome & FF but IE, `a={name:'AAA',age:19,}` because of the last comma `,`. But hold on, do you use any form in your HTML?

Comment: So, it could be the issue. If your button inside that form, after click the button, function will be called and the form will be submitted (mean the page could be reloaded). You just put `alert("clicked");` into beginning of your function to see that the function is called.

Answer (score 0):

the submit button already has a default functionality . it wont trigger the onclick function in many browsers. try changing the button type to 'button' and try to submit the form using javascript.