# Why isn't this show/hide script working?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, show-hide

I'm following a tutorial online for creating a show/hide function in javascript to an html5 form and from what I can see everything is spot on.  Dreamweaver isn't showing any syntax errors so I really don't understand why it's not working.

Here's the Javascript

```
function beginner(){
    var showA = document.getElementById("q1a1");
    var hideA = document.getElementByClassName("ab");

    for (var i = 0; i != hideA.length; i++){
        if(showA.clicked){
            hideA[i].style.display="block";
            }

         else{
             hideA[i].style.display = "none";
             }
        }/**for loop**/
    }/**function**/
```

here's the CSS

```
.qbox1{
    background-color:#0F9;
    width:600px;
    height:auto;
    margin:auto;
    }
.ab{
    background-color:#C63;
    width:600px;
    height:auto;
    margin:auto;
    display:none;
    }
.cd{
    background-color:#C63;
    width:600px;
    height:auto;
    margin:auto;
    display:none;
    }
.ques1{
    background-color:#09F;
    width:600px;
    height:auto;
    text-align:center;
    }
.anscont{
    background-color:#390;
    width:500px;
    height:40px;
    margin:auto;
    }
.left-label{
    background-color:#CC9;
    width:55px;
    height:20px;
    font-size:8pt;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
    }
.right-label{
    background-color:#CC9;
    width:55px;
    height:20px;
    font-size:8pt;
    text-align:center;
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    bottom:30px;
    right: 10px;
    }
.radcont{
    width:340px;
    height:40px;
    background-color:#096;
    margin:auto;
    }
.radbox{
    width:10%;
    height:40px;
    float:left;
    margin:auto;
    background-color:#CC9;
    }
.radbox label{
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
    }

.radbox input{
    margin:auto;
    width: 90%;
    display:block;
```

Here's the html

```
<form>
    <div class="qbox1">
        <div class="ques1">
        Where are you in terms of operating your Business?
        </div>
        <input type="radio" name="ques01" value="I just started planning everything" id="q1a1" onClick="beginner()">
        <label for="q1a1">I just started planning everything.</label><br />
        <input type="radio" name="ques01" value="I’ve been planning for a while and am working on getting it started once and for all." id="q1a2">
        <label for="q1a2">I’ve been planning for a while and am working on getting it started once and for all.</label><br />
        <input type="radio" name="ques01" value="I’m about to open soon." id="q1a3">
        <label for="q1a3">I’m about to open soon.</label><br />
        <input type="radio" name="ques01" value="I’m already open for Business." id="q1a4">
        <label for="q1a4">I’m about to open soon.</label><br />
    </div><br />
    <div class="ab">
        <div class="ques1">
            This is where the Question will go<br />
        </div>
        <div class="anscont">
            <div class="left-label">
                Left Text
            </div>
            <div class="radcont">
                <div class="radbox">
                    <label for="q2a1">1</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="question01" id="q2a1">
                </div>
                <div class="radbox">
                    <label for="q2a2">2</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="question01" id="q2a2">
                </div>
                <div class="radbox">
                    <label for="q2a3">3</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="question01" id="q2a3">
                </div>
                <div class="radbox">
                    <label for="q2a41">4</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="question01" id="q2a4">
                </div>
                <div class="radbox">
                    <label for="q2a5">5</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="question01" id="q2a5">
                </div>
                <div class="radbox">
                    <label for="q2a61">6</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="question01" id="q2a6">
                </div>
                <div class="radbox">
                    <label for="q2a7">7</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="question01" id="q2a7">
                </div>
                <div class="radbox">
                    <label for="q2a8">8</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="question01" id="q2a8">
                </div>
                <div class="radbox">
                    <label for="q2a9">9</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="question01" id="q2a9">
                </div>
                <div class="radbox">
                    <label for="q2a10">10</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="question01" id="q2a10">
                </div>
            </div> <!--radcont-->
            <div class="right-label">
                Right Text
            </div>
        </div><!--anscont-->
    </div><!--ab--><br />
            <div class="cd">
        <div class="ques1">
            This is where the Question will go<br />
        </div>
        <div class="anscont">
            <div class="left-label">
                Left Text
            </div>
            <div class="radcont">
                <div class="radbox">
                    <label for="q2a1">1</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="question01" id="q2a1">
                </div>
                <div class="radbox">
                    <label for="q2a2">2</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="question01" id="q2a2">
                </div>
                <div class="radbox">
                    <label for="q2a3">3</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="question01" id="q2a3">
                </div>
                <div class="radbox">
                    <label for="q2a41">4</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="question01" id="q2a4">
                </div>
                <div class="radbox">
                    <label for="q2a5">5</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="question01" id="q2a5">
                </div>
                <div class="radbox">
                    <label for="q2a61">6</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="question01" id="q2a6">
                </div>
                <div class="radbox">
                    <label for="q2a7">7</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="question01" id="q2a7">
                </div>
                <div class="radbox">
                    <label for="q2a8">8</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="question01" id="q2a8">
                </div>
                <div class="radbox">
                    <label for="q2a9">9</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="question01" id="q2a9">
                </div>
                <div class="radbox">
                    <label for="q2a10">10</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="question01" id="q2a10">
                </div>
            </div> <!--radcont-->
            <div class="right-label">
                Right Text
            </div>
        </div><!--anscont-->
    </div><!--cd--><br />

</form>
```

Comment: This is a really bad question for Stackoverflow. You need to ask more specific questions and not just dump your code and ask people to debug it for you. Did you even check your browser's console for errors? `getElementByClassName` has a typo. It should be `getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: well sometimes people don't know enough about what they're doing to be able to ask a more educated question than that, so I apologize for not being capable of being more specific, but thanks for pointing out the typo.

Comment: @DaMightyOptiq this is not a bad question, it would be bad if you didn't show any effort. Asking about whats wrong with your code it's perfectly valid.

Comment: You should also follow a more conventional JS style guide: https://github.com/airbnb/javascript

Comment: @Typo this *is* a bad question. It is completely off topic—"why isn't this code working?" OP should read the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to learn how to ask a proper, on-topic question.

Comment: @royhowie no it's not. Flag it then, ask for it to be closed.

Comment: @DaMightyOptiq sorry bit late in answering .. here is the working fiddle might help thats the reason posting this as comment not as answer [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Kri4shna/jt1hjvsf/)

Comment: To of any help debugging this, we need the error you're receiving, or the difference between actual and expected behavior.

Comment: @Typo I have voted to close and am not the only one who has.

Comment: @royhowie I'm glad you did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I could tell, you only had three mistakes:

1) `getElementByClassName` should be `getElementsByClassName`

2) There's no `.clicked` but `.checked`

3) On your `<input>` tag you have `onClick` when it should be `onclick`.

```js
function beginner(){
    var showA = document.getElementById("q1a1");
    var hideA = document.getElementsByClassName("ab");

    for (var i = 0; i != hideA.length; i++){
        if(showA.checked){
            hideA[i].style.display="block";
            }

         else{
             hideA[i].style.display = "none";
             }
        }/**for loop**/
    }/**function**/
```

```css
.qbox1{
    background-color:#0F9;
    width:600px;
    height:auto;
    margin:auto;
    }
.ab{
    background-color:#C63;
    width:600px;
    height:auto;
    margin:auto;
    display:none;
    }
.cd{
    background-color:#C63;
    width:600px;
    height:auto;
    margin:auto;
    display:none;
    }
.ques1{
    background-color:#09F;
    width:600px;
    height:auto;
    text-align:center;
    }
.anscont{
    background-color:#390;
    width:500px;
    height:40px;
    margin:auto;
    }
.left-label{
    background-color:#CC9;
    width:55px;
    height:20px;
    font-size:8pt;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
    }
.right-label{
    background-color:#CC9;
    width:55px;
    height:20px;
    font-size:8pt;
    text-align:center;
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    bottom:30px;
    right: 10px;
    }
.radcont{
    width:340px;
    height:40px;
    background-color:#096;
    margin:auto;
    }
.radbox{
    width:10%;
    height:40px;
    float:left;
    margin:auto;
    background-color:#CC9;
    }
.radbox label{
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
    }

.radbox input{
    margin:auto;
    width: 90%;
    display:block;
  }
```

```html
<form>
    <div class="qbox1">
        <div class="ques1">
        Where are you in terms of operating your Business?
        </div>
        <input type="radio" name="ques01" value="I just started planning everything" id="q1a1" onchange="beginner()">
        <label for="q1a1">I just started planning everything.</label><br />
        <input type="radio" name="ques01" value="I’ve been planning for a while and am working on getting it started once and for all." id="q1a2" onchange="beginner()">
        <label for="q1a2">I’ve been planning for a while and am working on getting it started once and for all.</label><br />
        <input type="radio" name="ques01" value="I’m about to open soon." id="q1a3" onchange="beginner()">
        <label for="q1a3">I’m about to open soon.</label><br />
        <input type="radio" name="ques01" value="I’m already open for Business." id="q1a4" onchange="beginner()">
        <label for="q1a4">I’m about to open soon.</label><br />
    </div><br />
    <div class="ab">
        <div class="ques1">
            This is where the Question will go<br />
        </div>
        <div class="anscont">
            <div class="left-label">
                Left Text
            </div>
            <div class="radcont">
                <div class="radbox">
                    <label for="q2a1">1</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="question01" id="q2a1">
                </div>
                <div class="radbox">
                    <label for="q2a2">2</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="question01" id="q2a2">
                </div>
                <div class="radbox">
                    <label for="q2a3">3</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="question01" id="q2a3">
                </div>
                <div class="radbox">
                    <label for="q2a41">4</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="question01" id="q2a4">
                </div>
                <div class="radbox">
                    <label for="q2a5">5</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="question01" id="q2a5">
                </div>
                <div class="radbox">
                    <label for="q2a61">6</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="question01" id="q2a6">
                </div>
                <div class="radbox">
                    <label for="q2a7">7</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="question01" id="q2a7">
                </div>
                <div class="radbox">
                    <label for="q2a8">8</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="question01" id="q2a8">
                </div>
                <div class="radbox">
                    <label for="q2a9">9</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="question01" id="q2a9">
                </div>
                <div class="radbox">
                    <label for="q2a10">10</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="question01" id="q2a10">
                </div>
            </div> <!--radcont-->
            <div class="right-label">
                Right Text
            </div>
        </div><!--anscont-->
    </div><!--ab--><br />
            <div class="cd">
        <div class="ques1">
            This is where the Question will go<br />
        </div>
        <div class="anscont">
            <div class="left-label">
                Left Text
            </div>
            <div class="radcont">
                <div class="radbox">
                    <label for="q2a1">1</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="question01" id="q2a1">
                </div>
                <div class="radbox">
                    <label for="q2a2">2</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="question01" id="q2a2">
                </div>
                <div class="radbox">
                    <label for="q2a3">3</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="question01" id="q2a3">
                </div>
                <div class="radbox">
                    <label for="q2a41">4</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="question01" id="q2a4">
                </div>
                <div class="radbox">
                    <label for="q2a5">5</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="question01" id="q2a5">
                </div>
                <div class="radbox">
                    <label for="q2a61">6</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="question01" id="q2a6">
                </div>
                <div class="radbox">
                    <label for="q2a7">7</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="question01" id="q2a7">
                </div>
                <div class="radbox">
                    <label for="q2a8">8</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="question01" id="q2a8">
                </div>
                <div class="radbox">
                    <label for="q2a9">9</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="question01" id="q2a9">
                </div>
                <div class="radbox">
                    <label for="q2a10">10</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="question01" id="q2a10">
                </div>
            </div> <!--radcont-->
            <div class="right-label">
                Right Text
            </div>
        </div><!--anscont-->
    </div><!--cd--><br />

</form>
```

Comment: it could also be the onClick call instead of onclick, here's a question related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380719/onclick-or-onclick

Comment: I didn't even see the onClick on the HTML, I assumed the listener logic was somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone, I got it to work, but now the else clause doesn't seem to be working but I'll post another question for that and try to ask it in a "better" way than this to avoid being ripped apart lol.

Comment: It's just about using another listener for that. If you do `onchange` it should work. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Well, you'll have to bind `onchange` on all of the radio buttons so it seem...

Answer (score -1):

Below line check the spelling of **getElementsByClassName** method

var hideA = document.getElementsByClassName("ab");

Also change showA.clicked into **showA.checked**

onClick should be **onclick**