# How to add onclick function from javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a button and add an onclick function to this button with javascript but there is a problem with onclick function. When I add button as below code I can't see quotation marks on Chrome. How can I add an onclick function with arguments?

```
myButton+= "<button onclick='addNewproperty('" + property + "','" + entry + "')' class='btn grey btn-circle' style='font-size: x-small; float: left'><i class='fa fa-times'></i>";
myButton+= entry.length > 12 ? entry.substring(0,12) + "..." : entry;
myButton+= "</button>"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may escape quotes. Since you were using same type of quotes as wrapper and inner quotes, it was actually acting like `<button onclick="addNewproperty("`.

```
myButton+= "<button onclick=\"addNewproperty('" + property + "','" + entry + "')\" class='btn grey btn-circle' style='font-size: x-small; float: left'><i class='fa fa-times'></i>";
myButton+= entry.length > 12 ? entry.substring(0,12) + "..." : entry;
myButton+= "</button>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use backticks **`** to wrap your variables.

```js
var hello = "Hello";
var myButton = "";
myButton+= "<button onclick='alert(`" + hello + "`)' class='btn grey btn-circle' style='font-size: x-small; float: left'><i class='fa fa-times'></i>";
myButton+= "</button>"

document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = myButton
```

```html
<div id="div">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4380741/5524404) answer and my self experience sometimes you shoud use onClick instead of onclick.

Answer (score 0):

For easier approach, you can add an `id` to your button element, eg:

```
myButton += "<button id='someId'>"
```

Then you can add onClick or any events to your element by:

```
document.getElementById("someId").addEventListener('click', function(){
   alert("Button clicked")
})
```