# I cannot link my Button output to my Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is a function that is part of a larger website I am designing. In a general sense I am trying to perform a Javascript function that will un-disable the disabled input HTML boxes from the click of a 'yes" button.

After clicking the "yes" button it seems it is not working.

Here is my code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
          function myFunction() {
          document.getElementById("first").disabled = false;
        }
</script>


 </head>
 <body>
      Perform Operation?: <br>
                <button onClick=myFunction()>Yes</button
                <div>
                    First Number: <input type="number" id="firstnumber" value=0 disabled><br>
                    Second Number: <input type="number" id="secondnumber" value=0 disabled><br>
                </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: `onClick` should be `onclick`!

Comment: Events in javascript are all lower case there is no camel case for events  `onclick` not `onClick`

Comment: <button onClick="myFunction()">Yes</button>

Answer (score 3):

You have written wrong selector here, check updated snippet below:

```js
 function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("firstnumber").disabled = false;
   document.getElementById("secondnumber").disabled = false;
}
```

```html
Perform Operation?: <br>
<button onClick=myFunction()>Yes</button
<div>
    First Number: <input type="number" id="firstnumber" value=0 disabled><br>
    Second Number: <input type="number" id="secondnumber" value=0 disabled><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is ok. Just you are using either wrong id or you have forgot to add the used id to your input. :-)

So either remove `extracharges` from below code and add `firstnumber` or `secondnumber` as per requirement or add input with `extracharges` as id.

`function myFunction() {
       document.getElementById("extracharges").disabled = false;
 }`

As pointed out in other answers and comments about case sensivity of JavaScript is right, but when you use event handlers as attribute (in html) then most of the browser understands it irrespective of its case.

Check this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380719/onclick-or-onclick) for more details!