# (Javascript) How do I link sub menu buttons to a function?

Tags: javascript, button, nested, submenu

I am getting close to done with a project, but I am stuck trying to link the buttons to my functions. I edited the menu successfully, but I need the buttons to link to my created functions.

For example when I look at the

```
<a href="#">Add a side to your Dice</a>
<a href="#">Remove a side to your Dice</a>
<a href="#">Add an additional Roll</a>
```

How would I add the functions so they actually do something?

```
onClick="promoteDice()
onClick="demoteDice()
onClick="addRoll()
```

Same thing with the tags:

```
  <a href="#roll">Roll</a>
  <a href="#exit">Exit</a>
```

I don't see where I am supposed to add the function so it works.

Here's my actual dice game for reference I don't need you to incorporate my script I just needed help with that question please.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
    <input type="button" value="Roll The Dice" onClick="rollDice()" />
    <input type="button" value="Upgrade The Dice" onClick="upgradeDice()" />
    <input type="button" value="Quit" onClick="quit()" />
<script>    
var myscore = 0;
var housescore = 0;
var dicesides = 6;
var diceroll = 1

function rollDice() {
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * dicesides) + 1;
  var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * dicesides) + 1;

  var total = x + y;
  msg = "You rolled " + x + ", " + y + " = " + total + "\n";
    if (total != 11 && total < 7 && x != y) {
            housescore += 1;
      msg += "Even Up";
        } else if (total != 11 && total > 7 && x != y) {
            myscore += 1;
      msg += "Player Up";
        }
  if (total == 7 || total == 11) {
    housescore += 10;
    msg += "CRAPS";
  } else if (x == y) {
    if (x % 2 == 0) {
      myscore += 10;
      msg += "Even Up";
    } else {
      housescore += 10;
      msg += "Odd Ball";
    }
  }
    msg += " Your Score is " + "Player: " + myscore + ", House: " + housescore;
  alert(msg);
    didIwin();

}
function didIwin() {
    if (housescore >= 100) {
    alert ("Sorry the house won the game!");
    } else if (playerscore >= 100) {
    alert ("Congratulations you won the game!");
    }
    myscore = 0;
    housescore = 0;
    dicesides = 6;
}
function upgradeDice() {
    if (myscore >= 10) {
    dicesides += 1;
    alert ("Your Dice now have " + dicesides + " sides");
    } else {
difference = 10 - myscore;
alert ("You need "+difference+" more points");
    }
}
function quit() {
  alert (" Your Score is " + "Player: " + myscore + ", House: " + housescore);
    myscore = 0;
    housescore = 0;
    dicesides = 6;
    }




</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Lastly here is the code for the Menu where I want to incorporate the functions:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#roll">Roll</a>
  <a href="#exit">Exit</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()">Upgrade
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
    <a href="#">Add a side to your Dice</a>
    <a href="#">Remove a side to your Dice</a>
    <a href="#">Add an additional Roll</a>
  </div>
  </div> 
</div>

<h3>Dropdown Menu inside a Navigation Bar</h3>
<p>Click on the "Dropdown" link to see the dropdown menu.</p>

<script>
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
  var myDropdown = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
    if (myDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
      myDropdown.classList.remove('show');
    }
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You would have to add those inline functions you're trying to call, like `onclick="promoteDice()"`, into your JS. eg `function promoteDice() { /* code here */ }`

Comment: I dont know if it matters, but `onclick` is typically lowercase.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380719/onclick-or-onclick

Comment: I finished the coding for Roll dice and Exit, how do I attach those to the buttons?  My script works fine but to finish I need the Upgrade button to have a sub menu which I will finish coding once I learn how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add the functions the same way that you did in the example before, it doesn't really matter that you are in a submenu or whatever.

Just add the `onclick` property and function to the HTML tag that you want to trigger the execution and then you are good to go.

In my example I added the function `myFunc();` to the add side to dice submenu, but you can add any logic and any other thing to the rest of the HTML tags, this was just an example.

As a side note: The code inside the function `myFunc();` can be changed into anything.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#roll">Roll</a>
  <a href="#exit">Exit</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()">Upgrade
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
    <a href="#" onclick="myFunc();">Add a side to your Dice</a>
    <a href="#">Remove a side to your Dice</a>
    <a href="#">Add an additional Roll</a>
  </div>
  </div> 
</div>

<h3>Dropdown Menu inside a Navigation Bar</h3>
<p>Click on the "Dropdown" link to see the dropdown menu.</p>

<script>

function myFunc() {
  alert('You clicked a submenu item')
}
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
  var myDropdown = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
    if (myDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
      myDropdown.classList.remove('show');
    }
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply add the onclick into the link like so:

```
<a href="#" onclick="promoteDice()">Add a side to your Dice</a>
<a href="#" onclick="demoteDice()">Remove a side to your Dice</a>
<a href="#" onclick="addRoll()">Add an additional Roll</a>
```

You may also want to use `<button type="button" onclick="addRoll()">Add Roll</button>` instead as the `<a>` tag should only be used when you are linking to something.