# Is using "onClick={}" considered a bad practise?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, event-handling

I learned that using `onclick` is considered a bad practise in HTML. Right now I'm going through a React tutorial. The tutorial uses `<button onClick={shoot}>Take the Shot!</button>`. Is this also considered a bad practise in React? And if it is, what is the "right" way to do it?

Comment: `onclick` or `onClick` ? In react, you should always use `onClick` with capital letter `C`

Comment: @Vencovsky are they different?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onclick or onClick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380719/onclick-or-onclick)

Comment: @ravibagul91 I don't think this is relevant to this question. This is asking if you should use `onClick` in React, not about the DOM API.

Comment: @VLAZ yes, check [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-galileo-fj6p8), you will see that in react, `onclick` don't work.

Comment: I used `onclick` for the HTML attribute. `onClick` is what my question is about, about React.

Comment: There's a whole [Handling Events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) section in the react docs that would have answered this for you

Comment: @Vencovsky thanks, I not too proficient in React. My first thought was that it's the same as the `onClick` HTML attrivute (well, more React-ified) as in it's case-insensitive but it seems it's not.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5871640

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `onclick` attribute in HTML is considered a bad practice because it decouples the function from the place where it was called from (among other things). If you read through the related JS files, it is unclear where a certain function was called from, and therefore its purpose is unclear. If you use `.addEventListener` from within JS, you keep the function and the purpose (the events that trigger it) together.

Reacts purpose is to keep the logic and the view together, so there is no decoupling possible at all. Therefore it is totally fine to use `onClick`, and it's the only right way I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

No, in React is the usual way to handle a click event. It is not a good practice to do something like `<button onClick={() => some_code_here}>Foo Bar</button>` because, in this way, you declare a new function on every render.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding more information about the differences of `onclick` and `onClick`.

In react, `onclick` won't work and `onClick` is handled by react as you can see in [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-galileo-fj6p8).

When using `onclick` it might also give you a warning

> Warning: Invalid event handler property `onclick`. Did you mean `onClick`?

There is some reasons why `onclick` is a bad practice, but in react, the correct way of handling clicks is passing a function to `onClick` prop.